# Firebase realtime database DataSnapshot value to Object conversion

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to convert DataSnapshot value to object. Its working fine, I believe that bean constructor(with arguments) used for conversion. I added some lines of code to perform some opeations, but lines of code I added never get executed. Sample bean class:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class DatabaseRecord {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String fullName;

    private DatabaseRecord() {
    }

    public DatabaseRecord(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        // following code not executing
        this.fullName = firstName + lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public String getFullName() { return fullName; }
}
```

Firebase online database flow:
[image]

Data fetch execution code:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference("/user/user1");
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        DatabaseRecord record = dataSnapshot.getValue(DatabaseRecord.class);
        Log.d(TAG, record.getFirstName()+":"+record.getLastName()+":"+record.getFullName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Output:

> Satish:Pandey:null

1. Google documentation shows parameterized constructor to set properties, if that is the case why not my code executing?
2. How to append my code after google conversion finishes in same bean object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the constructor that gets called is the parameterless since you are reading from the database using `getValue()`, which is required to map the values in the `DataSnapshot`. According to the doc, these are the rules you must follow to get the `DataSnapshot` data into a custom Java Class:

> - The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
> - The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized.

I you want to set the value for the property `fullName` you can do it in the same `getFullName()` method. Something like this:

```
public String getFullName() { 
    if(fullName == null){// it will be null the first time assuming the value doesn't exist in the database.
       fullName = getFirstName() + getLastName();
    }
    return fullName; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

The Firebase JSON deserializer uses the default (parameterless) constructor and then uses either setter methods or public fields for setting the values.

Most samples (and most real code I write) will have a parameterized constructor for regular creation of the objects, but that parameterized constructor is not used by Firebase.

I would probably make `getFullName()` a calculated value:

```
public String getFullName() { return firstName + lastName; }
```

Comment: I attached private access modifiers to properties and default constructor and don't have setter methods in my bean class but firebase fills values for firstName and lastName.

Comment: If there is no setter, Firebase tries to find a field that matches the JSON property and sets the value directly there.